# Continuously update a Label from code-behind during postbacks

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback

I am trying to add a Label to show the running total value from selections made in a RadioButtonList, CheckBoxList, and a DropDownList.  How do I go about adding that to my current code?

```
Protected Sub rblPhone_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rblPhone.SelectedIndexChanged
    lblPhonePrice.Text = "$" & rblPhone.SelectedItem.Value      
End Sub

Protected Sub cblAccessories_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cblAccessories.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim sumList As Integer = 0
    For Each accessory In cblAccessories.Items
        If accessory.Selected Then
            sumList = sumList + accessory.value
        End If
    Next
    lblAccPrice.Text = "$" & sumList    
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlPlan_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlPlan.SelectedIndexChanged
    lblPlanPrice.Text = "$" & ddlPlan.SelectedItem.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you thought about creating a separate function that will handle the calculation, return the value, and then in each of the `SelecedIndexChanged` events update the label?

Comment: I keep running into problems doing that.  Is there a simpler way that I am missing?

Comment: I think that's as simple as it gets. The other option would be to use JavaScript and avoid the whole postback.

Comment: Got your first suggestion to work this morning!  Thanks for leading me in the right direction!